# Page header full width with background color...but having transparent sections in between elements in header

Tags: html, css

I've been given a design which entails a header for a page to have a coloured background the full width of the `body`, but to have transparent borders between the `h1` and nav options in the header.

I've done a [jsfiddle for it here](http://jsfiddle.net/mfPFT/4/). If you imagine that the spaces to the left and right of the header were the same green as the middle of the header but you could still see the page underneath in between the nav options, then that is what I am trying to achieve.

It's an unusual style, and I've never come across it before, that's why I am struggling.

I could do something with JS on page load to solve this issue, but I want a pure CSS solution if it's possible. Be great if anyone has any ideas!

Comment: I've read this several times and I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS border-image property.

something like this, but then just for the right borders
and you can use a transparent png file for it:

```
.menu li{
-moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

apparently doesnt work in IE though..

here's the link to the w3schools page:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Comment: Yeah could do that, could also just use a background for the whole thing with transparent bits on the borders. Only thing with that is it forces me to have a fixed width for the header. which I am trying to avoid! it's a difficult one.